# Kendo-UI Angular Cannot Bind to Values

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using Angular 9 and Kendo-UI as my UI framework. I want to build a dynamic form builder, looked briefly into formly but to be honest it looks like it's Kendo-UI implementation is an after thought.

What I've done is create an interface that acts as the base input and then a bunch of interfaces that extend the base input that have all of the respective inputs based on the API documentation (e.g. [TextBoxComponent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/TextBoxComponent/)). For example, this is the `IBaseInput` interface along with the `ITextBox` interface:

```js
export interface IBaseInput {
    FormControlName: string;
    Label?: string;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    Type: 'autocomplete' | 'calendar' | 'checkbox' | 'colorgradient' | 'colorpalette' | 'colorpicker' | 'combobox' | 'datepicker' | 'dropdownlist' | 'dropdowntree' | 'maskedtextbox' | 'multiselect' | 'numerictextbox' | 'radiobutton' | 'rangeslider' | 'rangeslider' | 'slider' | 'switch' | 'textarea' | 'textbox';
}

export interface ITextBox extends IBaseInput {
    ClearButton?: boolean;
    ClearButtonIcon?: string;
    Disabled?: boolean;
    ErrorIcon?: string;
    MaxLength?: number;
    Placeholder?: string;
    ReadOnly?: boolean;
    SelectOnFocus?: boolean;
    ShowErrorIcon?: 'initial' | boolean;
    ShowSuccessIcon?: 'initial' | boolean;
    SuccessIcon?: string;
    TabIndex?: number;
    Title?: string;
    Value?: string;
    Blur?: (e: any) => void;
    InputBlur?: (e: any) => void;
    InputFocus?: (e: any) => void;
    Focus?: (e: any) => void;
    ValueChange?: (e: string) => void;
}
```

Then in my template, I attempt to build out the formfield, label, and control. For example, this is the code for the textbox:

```js
<kendo-formfield *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'">
    <kendo-label text="{{control.Label ? control.Label : control.FormControlName}}"></kendo-label>
    <kendo-textbox [clearButton]="control.ClearButton"
                   [clearButtonIcon]="control.ClearButtonIcon"
                   [disabled]="control.Disabled"
                   [errorIcon]="control.ErrorIcon"
                   [formControlName]="control.Format"
                   [maxLength]="control.MaxLength"
                   [placeholder]="control.Placeholder"
                   [readOnly]="control.ReadOnly"
                   [selectOnFocus]="control.SelectOnFocus"
                   [showErrorIcon]="control.ShowErrorIcon"
                   [showSuccessIcon]="control.ShowSuccessIcon"
                   [tabIndex]="control.TabIndex"
                   [title]="control.Title"
                   [value]="control.Value"
                   (blur)="control.Blur ? control.Blur($event) : null"
                   (inputBlur)="control.InputBlur ? control.InputBlur($event) : null"
                   (inputFocus)="control.InputFocus ? control.InputFocus($event) : null"
                   (focus)="control.Focus ? control.Focus($event) : null"
                   (valueChange)="control.ValueChange ? control.ValueChange($event) : null"></kendo-textbox>
</kendo-formfield>
```

The issue that I'm running into is that nearly every component is throwing the error when building the Angular project saying that it cannot bind. For example:

- Can't bind to 'clearButton' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-textbox'.
- Can't bind to 'clearButtonIcon' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-textbox'.
- Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-textbox'.
- etc...

So I immediately checked my module and I have the appropriate imports:

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { DropDownsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns';
import { InputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { LabelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-label';
import { LayoutModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormComponent } from './form.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        FormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        CommonModule,
        DateInputsModule,
        DropDownsModule,
        FormsModule,
        InputsModule,
        IntlModule,
        LabelModule,
        LayoutModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        FormComponent
    ]
})
export class FormModule { }
```

Since I have the appropriate imports, I'm not exactly sure what could be causing this. For what it's worth, this is my package.json dependency for the kendo-angular-inputs:

```json
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.0.0"
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at the `textbox.directive.d.ts` in the `@progress/kendo-angular-inputs/dist/es2015/textbox` directory, it appears as if the only inputs is `id`. Is this an instance where the API documentation doesn't line up with the actual implementation?

Comment: The textbox directive isn't relevant. It's a directive you can place on an input, apparently for styling purposes `<input kendoTextBox type="email" />`. You can read about it [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/TextBoxDirective/).

Comment: @Shai - Per the documentation, *Please note that the TextBox directive should be applied only for styling purposes. For fully functional inputs, check the TextBox Component.*

  : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/textbox/textbox-directive/

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote... In your update you wrote that you looked in the `textbox.directive.d.ts` file, so I just wanted to let you know that it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Shai - I see, the update section of my post is irrelevant because I was looking at the wrong file. Thank you.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` after you added `"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.0.0"` to your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Shai - Yes, I did. To confirm, I reran `npm install` followed by `ng build`, but the same errors are being returned.